# Will 12.04's network manager work on my Lenovo S12, it doesn't in 11.10?

Tags: wireless, 12.04, network-manager, release-upgrade

Network manager does not work on my Lenovo ideapad S12 (Intel Atom) laptop.  I had to replace Network manager to use a network.  Will the 12.04 upgrade keep WiCd or will Network Manger now work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happened.

- 12.04 kept WiCd
- I replaced Wicd with Network Manager and
- it worked (after a little jiggling)
- Wicd settings were kept.

Good job for the update manager folks, here.

---

The systray Wifi icon didn't properly display until I opened >System Settings >Hardware >Network

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was using 11.10 and here's how I fixed it.

http://solancer.blogspot.in/2011/10/network-icon-disappeared-in-ubuntu-1110.html

If the issue is with connecting an USB modem then using Gnome PPP dialer will solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately for me the icon appeared, it's just that Network Manager would not successfully connect to a network, while WiCd will.  WiCd has it's own problems, like not taking care of /etc/resolv.conf so that has to be done manually.