# How do I  disable local DNS caching?

Tags: lan, dnsmasq

I have a small private LAN with 6 Ubuntu systems. To improve performance and simplify maintenance I implemented a DNS server on my Debian firewall/router (dig shows 0ms on repeat lookups).

Will I be able to disable the new local DNS cache on my Ubuntu systems during or after the release-upgrade?

Reference:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop
- http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote my [own blog post](http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/):

> This dnsmasq server isn’t a caching server for security reason to avoid risks related to local cache poisoning and users eavesdropping on other’s DNS queries on a multi-user system.

So there's nothing to disable

Comment: My Lenovo S12 (Intel Atom) laptop doesn't use Network Manager (because it doesn't work) and uses WiCd.  WiCd doesn't properly configure /etc/resolv.conf with the nameserver address.  So will this change break my laptop's netowrk configuration? (See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/127209/will-12-04s-network-manager-work-on-my-lenovo-s12-it-doesnt-in-11-10)

Comment: Another confusing thing ⋯ http://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/dnsmasq says "In order to configure dnsmasq to act as cache for the host on which it is running, put "nameserver 127.0.0.1" in /etc/resolv.conf to force local processes to send queries to dnsmasq."  What would happen if I set there nameserver XX.XX.XX.XX to my local DNS server?

Comment: Well the good news is 12.04 installed, network manager now works, dnsmasq is being used and not being cached, all is well, thanks.

Comment: this half-cache just put stackoverflow down for me >_<