# What is the purpose of `dnsmasq` running listening on `127.0.0.1` interface?

Tags: networking, network-manager, xubuntu

I discovered an instance of `dnsmasq` running on my fresh install of `xubuntu` desktop. The general purpose of `dnsmasq` is known to be a DNS relay and DHCP server. The running process is reported as follows:

> /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.0.1 --conf-file=/var/run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec

Looks like it is spawned by `network-manager`. Contents of mentioned files are:

> #cat /var/run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf
>   server=192.168.2.1

In my local network `192.168.2.1` indeed is a DNS server.
I cannot understand why this instance of `dnsmasq` listens on `127.0.0.1` since I see no way to serve DNS relay and DHCP server on `127.0.0.1` interface.

Comment: Looks like a caching DNS server, am I correct?

Comment: What's the purpose of caching DNS info and make it available for `127.0.0.1` only?

Comment: Apparantly I was wrong, it's done in an attempt to improve latency issues. See [this AU question](http://askubuntu.com/q/127228/6969) which links to http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Would you please provide at least a short answer, so I can accept it for my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is the loopback address, it is not accessible by other machines, just the machine itself. According to the post http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/, this `dnsmasq` instance exists to improve performance by trying multiple DNS servers if one is too slow.

Comment: So for example if a server (like a proxy server) is running on localhost, there's no way other machines could use it? @Lekensteyn

Comment: @Shayan No it is not possible by default. You could set up a proxy (using socat for example) or an iptables NAT rule to redirect traffic, but this requires additional steps.

Answer (score -1):

It is a DNS server and it'd assign IP addresses to machines that request them from your computer. In this case it'd be used by NetworkManager to share your internet connection. Nothing to worry about :)

Comment: Assigning IP addresses is the role of DHCP server, not DNS server. This instance of `dnsmasq` doesn't play a role of DHCP server, since there's no `subnet` specification in the configuration file. Moreover, no requests from other machines can arrive from `127.0.0.1` which is the interface this instance is listening on.